# Cannot add more people to a group chat in iMessage

Tags: iphone, messages

How do I add people to an already existing group chat?

There are currently four people in the chat, three of the members are using an iPhone, and one is using a non-iPhone.

I am trying to add another person to the group chat, how do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add people to a group message if one or more of the people does not have an iPhone.  You also cannot add people to an already existing iMessage group chat if they do not have an iPhone.
In this case, one of the people that was in the group chat doesn't have an iPhone. (You can tell because it doesn't have a FaceTime option next to the call and message button.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm on iOS 10 Beta 7 (14A5345a) and while in the message if you tap on the "i" icon on top right you'll then have a button "+ Add Contact"

Comment: I'll have to test this before accepting,

Comment: Sure thing, I would've captured a screenshot but since there are other people on there and I'm not sure on how to blur them out therefore I rather chose not to attach one

Comment: You can upload it to your computer and use MSPaint(Microsoft paint) to edit it out. I just upgraded to public beta 6 and it won't let me update to iOS 10 PB 7. I'm on iPhone 6

Comment: I know but I'm not gonna get to a computer before tomorrow

Comment: Ok, look at the photo I added In my edit

Comment: I now see that you've updated there beta version you're on and unfortunately Beta 7 isn't yet available to the public

Comment: Ok. Do you know when I will be able to get it? Also, am I able to add not apple users into a group message that already exists?

Comment: I don't know when that will be available and you cannot add only users who are registered with iMessages momentarily

Comment: One of my friends doesn't have an iPhone but he's in it

Comment: @Alex in that case there's a work around by instead of going into that message conversation tap on the new messages icon and type in one of those names who were in the original conversation and you should automatically get suggestions with those people who are already in your previous conversation so by tapping that you'll get back into that thread and also be able to add more users to it. Although it might then start s new conversation thread but that's the way it seems to be like by design since in reality there's an added participant

Comment: I updated to iOS public beta 7, and I still don't see the button anywhere :(

Comment: @Alex this must be due to this one contact that's not on iMessage and I'm that case I'd suggest you to follow the instructions of my previous comment which does work as I've tested it with group messages that does include a combination of users that do and don't have iMessage